# The explanation of MPPT and its main function

Tags: power, efficiency, mppt

I think the main function of MPPT is to find the max output power for us to let the power efficiency become the MAX.

However,i am still not quite understand MPPT.Is MPPT a schematic or an algorithm?We usually see a point of MPPT ,which is the top point of the output power curve.then what should we modify to let the output power become and keep the value which is the same as MPPT?

Maybe i don't ask the question clearly,but i have done my best to ask my question,i hope someone can understand what i ask,and tell me the answer.

Comment: No, you haven't done your best.  The sloppy writing is rather annoying to read.  The word "I" is always capitalized, for one thing.  Disrespecting the volunteers here is not a good way to get free help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think the main function of MPPT is to find the max output power

Yes.

> for us to let the power efficiency become the MAX.

That depends on the definition of "efficiency" (for example a gasoline engine may not have max efficiency at max power).

> However,i am still not quite understand MPPT. Is MPPT a schematic or an algorithm?

"Maximum Power Point Tracking" isn't even an algorithm, it is simply a principle, a description of "a system that will adjust certain parameters to make sure it will operate at maximum available power depending on current conditions".

An algorithm/schematic are ways to implement this in a particular context.
For example, choosing the optimum gear on a bicycle is MPPT. In this case the implementation consists of an algorithm in your head, force sensors in your tendons, plus a mechanical drive train with multiple gears.

> We usually see a point of MPPT ,which is the top point of the output power curve.

Yes, but keep in mind the curve itself depends on variations in what powers the generator (sunlight, wind speed, etc) so for these variable sources your MPPT will need to be able to react to changes in conditions.

> what should we modify to let the output power become and keep the value which is the same as MPPT?

In the case of a solar panel, one possible algorithm ([there are others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_power_point_tracking#Classification)) is Perturb & Observe: draw a little more current, then a little less, and measure the voltage, then compute the power in both cases. Then increase or decrease the current depending on which value gave more power, and repeat.

If your power source is a windmill, or anything else, some of these algorithms may still work, or others may be better.

Answer (score 0):

MPPT stands for *Maximum Power Point Tracking*.

> schematic or an algorithm?

*Think* about it.  A schematic is just a visual representation of a circuit, so clearly can't track anything.  Of these two choices, that leaves "algorithm".  What do you think it is?  "Maximum power point tracking" seems rather clear in this context.  What does it mean to you?